# JS or Python frameworks/widgets to build spreadsheet web app with database capabilities a.k.a. Airtable replica

Tags: javascript, python, web-applications, widget, airtable

I am an intermediate level Python and Javascript dev starting a project to develop a web-based minimally viable alternative to https://airtable.com/ a spreadsheet and database hybrid app. I will be implementing only some of the functions though. Primarily interested in the drag and drop rows and objects, kanban/gallery views, ability to link and view attachments, ability to switch from row format to form format, real-time collaboration, pivot table functionality and ability to produce report templates - extracts, charts, tables. What I have discovered so far is that there are some companies out there that sell widgets with some of these functionalities e.g.

1. https://ej2.syncfusion.com/demos/#/material/kanban/overview.html
2. https://www.htmlelements.com/demos/page-templates/project-tracker/
3. https://webix.com/pivot/

But its hard to tell how feasible it is to use these for such a project esp. with the ability to connect them together if they are from different widget stores. Question is: is it worth buying widgets or are there some other opensource, free alternatives, or should I just try to build from scratch? Would love to hear from folks who have built similar apps. Any pointers to other resources on this topic would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It mainly depends on the project. For most of the tasks and projects open source is fine. For more advanced usage, the price of a license from any of these companies compared to what you need to do is OK.

Comment: Thanks @scripto!  Do you have any suggestions for open sources alternatives I should consider?

Comment: The htmlelements.com Table component is free so you can use it instead of the DataGrid

Comment: Thank you @scripto, as an update - I am now looking at https://htmlelements.com, https://www.ag-grid.com/ (Javascript) , and https://baserow.io/ (Python). Hopefully this will help others looking to do something similar.